# Проблема с зависимостью пакетов chromium-gost

Tags: linux, chromium

Установил chromium-gost версии 80.0.3987.116, но при установке возникла проблема с зависимостью пакетов.

sudo apt install -f выдает:
"Зависит: libappindicator3-1 но он не может быть установлен."
"Рекомендуется: libu2f-udev"

Пробовал отдельно установить пакет libu2f-udev, но ошибка не пропала.

Как можно решить данную проблему?

Операционная система Astra Linux 1.6 Smolensk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуй поставить пакет из дебиана

https://packages.debian.org/search?suite=all&section=all&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=libappindicator3-1

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо за совет, проблема решилась после установки данных пакетов:
libappindicator3-1
libdbusmenu-glib4
libdbusmenu-gtk3-4
libindicator3-7